# Font Not Rendered Properly in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have used a font using @font-face in CSS.

The problem is that the font is displayed properly in firefox but not Google Chrome.

There is some boldness in firefox which is not shown by Chrome.

Any my website URL: [www.learnpro.tk](http://www.learnpro.tk) to check yourself how it looks different the text written in RED Background.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like http://www.fontconverter.org/
Since not all browsers use the same extension for their fonts.

Also, while looking with firebug at your website ... fonts (chrome.ttf and certified.ttf) were not loaded correctly

Comment: I have checked .ttf is supported in both.  Please revisit my site as it was not properly uploaded. Sorry for this.

Comment: I noticed that @font-face makes the text somewhat thicker in Firefox and IE which is not done by Google Chrome.